# gnupg on Arch Linux broken since readline upgrade - can't find libreadline.so.6

Tags: arch-linux, readline, gnupg

I've just upgraded readline to a new major release:

```
$ grep readline.*7 /var/log/pacman.log 
[2016-11-15 21:53] [ALPM] upgraded readline (6.3.008-4 -> 7.0-1)
```

Since this GNUPG is broken:

```
$ gpg 
gpg: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That also means I can't upgrade any packages. How do I *safely* fix my installation?

What I've tried so far to [downgrade](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages) readline:

- The package is not in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`
- Building from the [previous PKGBUILD](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/readline&id=c4138f87c673743814dc6bbde2b225e8f65f7da0) failed because it doesn't bootstrap itself - it relies on `awk` which is also missing `libreadline.so.6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been reported to Arch [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/51818).

The workaround is to run

```
mkinitcpio -P
```

after the upgrade has completed, but before rebooting.

If you've rebooted before re-running mkinitcpio, then you'll need to boot off e.g. a USB key and run the mkinitcpio from the chroot.  The easiest is to use [arch-chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root) as in the [Arch install instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide).

I haven't had a chance to test this method in this particular case, however have done so in the past.

Comment: Upvoted. The only correct answer.

Comment: @jasonwryan I am confused. The linked bug report is about issues with LVM. This answer will fix problems during the init process, but that is not what the OP is asking about. I don't see how rebuilding the RAM disk is going to allow gpg to find `libreadline.so.6` if it has been upgraded to `libreadline.so.7`.

Comment: @StrongBad read the mkinitcpio developer's (Dave Reisner) comment: this is an ordering issue: everything else (lvm, gpg etc) is just noise...

Comment: I can't reproduce any longer, of course, but marking as accepted since it's the "official" solution.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by manually verifying and installing an older version:

1. Download the previous release from [Arch Linux Archive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive)
2. Copy the package and signature file to *another* machine and verifying the signature there
3. [Unpack the package](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1284861#p1284861): `sudo tar -xvpf readline-6.3.008-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz -C / --exclude .PKGINFO --exclude .INSTALL`

Warning: Other packages may contain pre- or post-install scripts. This one did not, but consider yourself warned!

Comment: By downgrading, you potentially leave your system in an unsupported partially upgraded state. An alternative is to upgrade packages until `pacman` works.

Comment: I did immediately upgrade afterwards, so it should now be in a stable state.

Answer (score 3):

It seems `libreadline.so.7` is backward compatible enough for most utilities to keep working after running:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.6
```

After that it warned me that `/usr/bin/bash: Symbol rl_readline_state has different size in shared object, consider re-linking`, but I was able to update `pacman-key` and upgrade `libgcrypt` so that new packages would validate, and then `pacman -S bash` to rebuild my shell using `readline 7.0`.

After you've put out pacman's Catch-22-style fires, simply clean up with:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libreadline.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by editing `/etc/pacman.conf` and uncomenting or adding this line under `[options]`:

```
SigLevel = Never
```

Save and run `pacman -Syyu`, it updates the system and repairs it. Then comment that line again and update the database.

Comment: That is **not** secure.

Comment: Not that isn't, but it works when you're hurry up, like me that day.

Answer (score 0):

I did what @chbrown suggests:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.6
```

(also had linking warning)

Then I had a new error regarding ca-certificates-utils so I had to follow this: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/53217#comment155971

```
pacman -Sy --force  ca-certificates-utils
```

And then I could:

```
pacman -Syu
```

And all the upgrades went well and the libreadline/libreadline linking error was fixed.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you have gotten your system into a weird partially upgraded state, but partial upgrades are [not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported). The solution is that:

> A simple pacman -Syu to a properly synced mirror will fix the problem as long as pacman is not broken.

Your problem is that `pacman` seems to be broken. You may be lucky and can fix things by simply turning [package signing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Package_signing) off. If you are worried about security, you can manually download the packages you need on another machine, check their signatures, and then add them to the package cache on the broken machine.

If in fact `pacman` is broken, then you need to [manually reinstall pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Manually_reinstalling_pacman). This basically requires you to download the pacman dependencies and manually extract them in the correct places. Which packages need to be reinstalled depends on the exact state of your system.

Comment: Turning off package signing is not a safe option, I'm afraid.

Comment: @l0b0 see edit. Arch did not have package signing for years, but if you are worried about security, you can manually download the packages on another machine and check the signatures.

Comment: Further, `pacman -Syu` will _not_ necessarily solve this (as of this comment). In some cases, it can be the source of such issues.

Comment: @StrongBad Please see my answer.