# Pacman: Corrupted Packages

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I've just started using Manjaro Linux, but my pacman appears to have become messed up.

When I try to install any package, I get an error along the lines of this:

```
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine
error: lemonbar-xft: missing required signature
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/lemonbar-xft-269.00a3fe6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
```

However, when I run `sudo pacman-key --init`
it says:

```
gpg: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/etc/pacman.d/gnupg//trustdb.gpg': No such file or directory
gpg: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
gpg: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
==> ERROR: Trust database could not be updated.
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have system in partially-upgraded state.

First of all, don't close your terminal since most probably bash won't work without readline.

Secondly, try to search for `readline-7.0*` in your /var/cache/pacman/pkg, or download old package from [arch linux archive](https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/r/readline/). You will need to extract readline and install missing .so file yourself.

Read more about similar issue here: [gnupg on Arch Linux broken since readline upgrade - can't find libreadline.so.6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323550/gnupg-on-arch-linux-broken-since-readline-upgrade-cant-find-libreadline-so-6/323554#323554)

Comment: I tried to install readline-8.0.tar.gz, but I get the same error: ```awk: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
config.status: error: could not create Makefile``` when trying to do ```./configure```

Comment: You need to download readline-7.0, probably the latest version, from package cache or from archive link. Than you need to unpack the package and copy libreadline.so.7 file to /usr/lib using sudo. Please read the instructions in the answer that I referenced.